# Can I see what hats others have been awarded?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

Is there a way to see all the hats another user has earned/been awarded? I'm nosy/curious. Also, I'm trying to figure out secret hats.

Answer (score 15):

Just go to their [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2675154/honk?tab=topactivity), make sure the Activity tab is selected and click the blue hat.

[image]
[image]

For a *list* of secret hats, you can visit [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/295232).

Comment: right! activity tab!  SO is hard!

Comment: you have no hats  in your profile